# preg_match to return multiple values from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to extract two values from some URLs.

Example URLs:

- `cricket-ck-game-play`
- `hand-ball-hb-game-play`
- `volley-ball-vb-game-play`
- `soccer-sc-game-play`

I want extract the **full game name** and its **short name** separately ignoring the `-game-play` part at the end of the URL.

I've tried the following code which returns 'ck', 'hb', 'vb', 'sc', but not the **full name**.

```
preg_match("/(?<=-)[^-]*(?=-game-play)/", $uri, $game);
```

Actual results I am getting:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "ck"
}
```

Expected Results:

```
case:1 (In case of example 1) -  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "cricket"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "ck"
}

case:2 (In case of example 2) - array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "hand-ball"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "hb"  
}
```

Comment: Are the parts before `ck` etc always more than 2 chars and are the short names always 2 chars? Are they always characters a-z?

Comment: Yes the parts before 'ck' are always more than 2 chars and also the short names are always 2 chars and are always alphabets only(can be capitals sometimes or Uc sort of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match("/(.+)-([a-z]{2})-/i", $uri, $game);
```

Grabs everything before two letters bordered by dashes, and then grabs those two letters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this expression might be somewhat close to what you have in mind:

```
(.*)-(.{2})(?=-game-play)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/NNTLag/1/)

or

```
(.*)-(.*)(?=-game-play)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OrxA8M/1/)

Comment: Does not result in desired output.  Game name can have a hyphen in it.

Comment: @Emma Thanks! Your condition 1 worked like a charm!

Comment: These work, but you don't need the lookahead. `(.*)-(.*)-game-play` is very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If the parts before the short name are always more than 3 chars and the short name always consists of 2 chars `[a-zA-Z]` you could use 2 capturing groups, using quantifiers `{3,}` and `{2}` to match the characters.

```
\b(\w{3,}(?:-(?:\w{3,}))*)-(\w{2})-game-play\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(` Capture *group 1*

  - `\w{3,}` Match 3+ times a word char
  - `(?:-\w{3,})*` Repeat 0+ times matching `-` and 3 or more word chars
- `)` close group
- `(` Capture *group 2*

  - `[a-zA-Z]{2}` Match 2 times a word char (As per the comments)
- `)` Close group
- `-game-play` Match literally
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lqokvZ/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/5oMPE)

Another option is to use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and split on 2 chars a-z surrounded by hyphens in a capturing group and match the rest:

```
$pattern = "/-([a-z]{2})-.*/";
$str = "cricket-ck-game-play";
print_r(preg_split($pattern, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => cricket
    [1] => ck
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ZcPO9)